# Unhandled System.NullReferenceException in Table Adapter Fill

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I keep getting null value expression when the variable sDate does not exist in the data table.  It works fine as long as there is a corresponding date in the table.  dvtta is the Table Adapter.  Here is what I have so far:

```
            object StartingBal = 0;
            StartingBal = (decimal)dvtta.Balance(acctno, sDate);
            if (StartingBal.GetType() != typeof(DBNull))
            {
                StartingBal = (decimal?)StartingBal;
                StartingBalance = Convert.ToDecimal(StartingBal);
            }
            else
            {
                StartingBalance = 0;
            }
```

I've been pulling my hair out on this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for Balance:

```
 SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS Expr1
 FROM     Trans
 WHERE  (ACCT = @account) AND (Date <= @baldate)
```

Comment: It is a select statement that returns the balance based upon the date.  The date I pass to it is never null.

Comment: sDate is never null.  It is always some valid date.  The problem is that date may not be in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
if (StartingBal != null) { /* etc. */ }
```

If it isn't returning anything then aren't you setting your object StartingBal = null. In VB.NET this would be "StartingBal Is Nothing" which worked for me in a very similar situation.